# RestSharp does not deserialize properties with pascal case and underscore

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using RestSharp in an application that expects JSON like the following

```
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "Material_Composition": "material composition",
    "MaterialComposition_FirstChoice": "material composition first choice" 
}]
```

The object that the json above should be deserialized to is of type MaterialCompositionInfo

```
public class MaterialCompositionInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Material_Composition")]
    public string MaterialComposition { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("MaterialComposition_FirstChoice")]
    public string MaterialCompositionFirstChoice { get; set; }
}
```

The API call is made as follows:

```
var baseUrl = "some url";
RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl );
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<List<MaterialCompositionInfo>>(request);
```

I get the correct values for Id and MaterialComposition in the response.Data, however, MaterialCompositionFirstChoice is always null even though the correct value is returned and it's part of the response.Content

I tried to change the default serializer and use JSON.Net's instead of the default but I got the same result. I also tried to use JsonPropertyName instead of JsonProperty, that didn't work either.

Comment: Your JSON is a single `MaterialCompositionInfo` object, but you try to deserialize the response as `List<MaterialCompositionInfo>`. I doubt that you able to *get the correct values for Id and MaterialComposition*.

Comment: @YongShun I was just showing the json property names. I mentioned that other properties are being deserialized correctly. I'll edit my question to make it clear that the json returned is an array.

Answer (score 0):

The [default serialiser](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#json) in RestSharp is `System.Text.Json`, but you are using attributes from `Newtonsoft.Json` and it naturally doesn't work.

You either need to use the `Newtonsoft.Json` [serialiser for RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#newtonsoftjson-aka-json-net) with those attributes, or apply `[JsonPropertyName("...")]` attribute instead.

Comment: maybe it was not clear from my question but I tried your suggestions. Would be helpful to provide a working example with the same property names I used.

Comment: What version of RestSharp are you using?

Comment: am using version 106.11.2

Comment: It's an old version, I can't really help with that, sorry.